# Replacing elements in vector using erase and insert

Tags: c++, vector, insert, iterator, erase

```
void replace(vector<string> my_vector_2, string old, string replacement){

    vector<string>::iterator it;
    for (it = my_vector_2.begin(); it != my_vector_2.end(); ++it){

        if (*it==old){
            my_vector_2.erase(it);
            my_vector_2.insert(it,replacement);

        }
    }

}
```

So, I'd like this function to replace all occurrences of the string old in the vector with the string replacement. But when calling this function, it simply doesn't change the vector at all. I'm not sure if I am using the erase and insert functions properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you pass the vector as a _reference_?

Comment: Ah man, I feel so stupid right now....Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to erase and insert. Just assign: `*it = replacement;`. That eliminates any issues about iterator invalidation, and removes a bunch of churning to remove an element then open up a hole for insertion where that element used to be.

Answer (score 9):

At first you need to pass vector by reference, not by value.

```
void replace(vector<string>& my_vector_2, string old, string replacement){
```

Second erase and insert [invalidates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) it, you need to update it with new iterator returned by erase

```
it = my_vector_2.erase(it);  
it = my_vector_2.insert(it,replacement);
```

Comment: Isn't this UB? Mentioning `it` after the call to `erase` is UB, and you do mention `it` in your call to `insert`. I think you have to use a workaround with `std::distance`.

Comment: @Enn - did you not notice that `it` is assigned with the *result* of `erase()`?  The invalidated iterator cannot be used, because `it` now holds a valid iterator; the same is true for the following `insert()` line.

Answer (score 5):

There's an ready-made [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) for your problem:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> v;  // populate

std::replace(v.begin(), v.end(), "old", "new");
```

Comment: It may or may not be worth noting that this deduces `T` in `replace` as `char[4]`. Operations that mix `string` and `const char*` should be efficient, so I don't think it matters in this case, but if you want to pass in string literals with different lengths then you need a conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing your `std::vector` as a value. In order to Change the `std::vector` you pass to the function, declare it as a reference

```
void replace(vector<string>& my_vector_2, string old, string replacement){ }
```

The `&` denotes that you pass your `std::vector` by reference and so you can access the object you passed.

And don't erase the element, simply replace it.